Handling missing information in continuation ratio model - censoring?
I am fitting a continuation ratio model in R by first using rms::cr.setup() to put the data into "person-threshold" or "person-period" format, then fitting a logistic regression. (As described, e.g., in Cole & Ananth, 2001.) My outcome concerns how far along a "treatment cascade" each individual got:
1 - need treatment but not referred
2 - referred (but didn't attend intake)
3 - attended intake (but <14 days of treatment)
4 - >= 14 days of treatment

My problem is that for some individuals, we know that they attended the intake, but have no information on how long they stayed in treatment. In other words, we know their value on the outcome is >=3, but don't know if the true value is 3 or 4.
I've read that a continuation ratio model can be conceptualized as a discrete survival or hazard model with a logistic link (e.g., Cole & Ananth, 2001; Suresh et al., 2022; Tutz & Schmid, 2016, p. 38). Given this, can I right censor the cases where I don't know whether they progressed beyond intake / level 3? And how would I implement this?
Figure 1 from Suresh et al. seems to suggest that I can do this by adding rows up to the point of censoring, but set all values to 0 for those cases (e.g., ID 2 censored at interval 4, ID 3 censored at interval 5):

But I'm really not sure.

You can think about this as follows: if you only have a lower limit to the outcome for an individual, then that individual provides no information about outcomes of higher values. Omitting that individual during evaluation of higher outcome values allows the individual to contribute information up to her own last observed value without contaminating evaluation of higher-valued outcomes.
"Adding rows up to the point of censoring, but set[ing] all [event] values to 0 for those cases" is thus how to proceed.
I'd suggest, however, that you think about how that principle was applied for ID2 in your example. If the dropout time was 3.4, it seems that the value of 0 at $t_4$ is after the point of censoring. From the perspective of right-censored values, that individual's event time is certainly after $t_3$ but you don't know that the event time was after $t_4$. Thus the correct right-censoring time (last time to include in the person-period data format) would seem to be $t_3$, not $t_4$.
Note that you don't have to restrict yourself to logistic regression once you have the data in person-period format. Any link function appropriate for a binary regression can be considered. For example, a complementary log-log link (instead of the logit link used for logistic regression) ends up being equivalent to a proportional hazards model when event times are grouped.

Extremely helpful, thank you. Is there any reason to generally prefer a cloglog link in this situation, or would it just depend on my data / questions / etc?

@zephryl I don't see an advantage to cloglog in this situation, just wanted to let you know that there can be other choices in more general cases. My understanding is that logit link is standard in continuation-ratio models (but i don't typically encounter them in my work). A couple more things: (1) Think about whether the hard break at 14 days is useful. If you know the actual number of days, you could model the number of days directly with this approach. (2) Is there come known competing risk that might explain treatment drop-out? That could also be modeled.

Wonderful information in the OP and @EdM’s answer.  I tried comparing coefficients from a log-log of clog-log link with a CR model fit and didn’t get exact agreement so I’ve never really understood the relationship.  Note that if using a logit link (proportional odds model) I allow for interval censoring of current outcome states in a state transition model using Bayesian modeling in the rmsb package.
